# Rails the best way to scope vars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, scope

i have a 'Course' model that has the following attributes;

```
Course
  Price - float 
  Featured - boolean
```

My question would be the following, I need 4 lists in my controller, recent courses, paid courses, free courses and featured courses.

It would be good practice to write my controller as follows?

```
def index
  @courses = Course.order(created_at: :desc)

  @free_courses = []
  @courses.map {|c| @free_courses << c if c.price == 0}

  @premium_courses = []
  @courses.map {|c| @premium_courses << c if c.price> 0}

  @featured_courses = []
  @courses.map {|c| @featured_courses << c if c.featured}
end
```

Or do the consultations separately?

```
def index
  @courses = Course.order(created_at: :desc)
  @free_courses = Course.where("price == 0")
  @premium_courses = Course.where("price > 0")
  @featured_courses = Course.where(featured: true)
end
```

I checked through the logs that the first option is more performance but I am in doubt if it is an anti partner.

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally bad practice to iterate over all records in the database in Rails (i.e. `Course.map` or `Course.all`) both for performance and memory usage. As your database grows this becomes exponentially problematic.  It's much better to use `Course.where()` methods.  You'll probably want a default sort order so you can add with one line in your model.

```
default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }
```

Then you can just do this in controller and they'll have the sort by default:

```
@courses = Course.all
```

I would also suggest adding scopes to your model for easier access.
So in your course.rb file

```
scope :free -> { where("price == 0") }
scope :premium -> { where("price > 0") }
scope :featured -> { where(featured: true) }
```

Then in your controller you can just do:

```
@courses = Course.all
@free_courses = Course.free
@premium_courses = Course.premium
@featured_courses = Course.featured
```

These scopes can also be chained if you need to combine those so you could do things like:

```
@mixed_courses = Course.premium.featured
```

As others have explained, `Model.where()` executes the selection of data by passing sql inside `where("Write Pure SQL QUERIES HERE")` where as regular ruby enumerable methods (`.map`) iterate over array which must be instantiated as ruby objects. That's where the memory / performance issues take the hit.  It's ok if you're working with small data sets, but anything with data volume will get ugly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: My answer -"These scopes can also be changed" typo should be "These scopes can also be chained".  Is there something about my answer that doesn't warrant an upvote?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The second approach will become faster than the first as the size of the Course table increases. The first approach has to iterate over every record in the table 4 times. The second approach creates a Relation of only the records that match the where clause, so it does less work.

Also, the second approach has the advantage of laziness. Each query is only run at the time it is used, so it can be changed further along the code path. It's more flexible.

Note that it would be an improvement to the second approach to create scopes on the Course model that handles the logic. For example, one each for courses, free_courses, premium_courses and featured courses. This has the advantage of putting database logic in the model instead of the controller, where it can more easily be reused and maintained.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is better because when you use the .where() method, you are arranging the query in database itself rather than by the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer